# MySQL delete last 4 letters

Tags: mysql

I need a MySQL query (if PHP is required you can use that too) that will delete the ending of all the values on one column named 'url'.

The problem is that I saved the urls having the `.php` and now I want to delete that ending from all the values in the database.

Example:

old values:

```
my_url.php
my_sadas.php
```

new values:

```
my_url
my_sadas
```

Comment: Use `SUNSTRING()` and `LENGTH()` functions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html

Comment: @ypercube: you mean `SUBSTRING()` right?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
UPDATE mytable
SET myfield = SUBSTRING(myfield, 1, LENGTH(myfield)-4) ;
```

If you want to also check whether the field ends with `'.php'` before truncating, you can add this condition:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET myfield = SUBSTRING(myfield, 1, LENGTH(myfield)-4)
WHERE RIGHT(myfield, 4) = '.php' ;
```

Oh, there's also `LEFT()` which can be used instead of `SUBSTRING()` as well

And `CHAR_LENGTH()` should be used instead of `LENGTH()` as it is multi-byte safe (while `LENGTH()` is not):

```
UPDATE mytable
SET myfield = LEFT(myfield, CHAR_LENGTH(myfield)-4)
WHERE RIGHT(myfield, 4) = '.php' ;
```

Comment: substring character positions aren't 0 indexed. You need to use 1 as the base point.

Answer (score 4):

```
UPDATE files
SET fileName = SUBSTRING(fileName, 1 , (LENGTH(fileName) - 4)) ;
```

Comment: Please update your code-only answer to incorporate your commented knowledge in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

For the case where you might have double byte characters, you might want to use `CHAR_LENGTH`
instead of `LENGTH`, and `LEFT` instead of `SUBSTRING`.

Combining this with the desire to only remove the characters if they are `.php`, either a `CASE` or the `WHERE` clause.

```
UPDATE table SET field = CASE WHEN INSTR(field, '.php') > 0 THEN LEFT(field, INSTR(field, '.php')) ELSE field END
```

or

```
UPDATE table SET field = LEFT(field, INSTR(field, '.php')) WHERE INSTR(field, '.php') > 0
```

Answer (score 2):

SUBSTRING_INDEX is easier to use for this case.

```
UPDATE mytable
SET
    mytable.url = SUBSTRING_INDEX(mytable.url, '.php', 1)
WHERE
    mytable.url LIKE "%.php"
```